# Which scripture mentions the yuga in which Ramayana and Mahabharata took place?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, yuga

As far as I know, they themselves don't mention this.  Which scripture actually has this reference?

Answer (score 2):

Mahabharata 1.2

> antare chaiva samprApte **kalidvAparayorabhUt** | samantapa~nchake yuddhaM kurupANDavasenayoH || 9||
>
> It was at this same Samantapañcaka that **at the juncture of the dvApara yuga and the kali yuga** the war between the armies of the Kurus and the Pāndavas was fought.